# Why structural rules define the "smallest relation" satisfying the rules?

Tags: operational-semantics, higher-order-logic

I'm following a university course based on [these slides](http://www.diag.uniroma1.it//degiacom/didattica/metodiformali/aa2014-15/materiale/3-Pre-Post-program-analysis/3-1-StructuralOperationalSemantics-2up.pdf), and I have a question about structural operational semantics.

As you can see at page 7 (4-th slide), a structural rule is interpreted logically as: `∀(antecedent ∧ side-condition ⊃ consequent)`. Then it says that "The structural rules define inductively a relation, namely: the smallest relation satisfying the rules"t.

I know the definition of "smallest relation", but may someone give me an intuition behind it in this context? For instance, provide a concrete example indicating which is such "smallest relation".

Comment: The complete relation also satisfies the rules, but is not so useful.